Playwright (node) can't see the secret env variable from Azure Pipeline
I am building a pipeline in Azure to run some tests in Playwright.
I am getting secret password from Azure keyvault and storing it as a variable - which works between steps / scripts in pipeline as expected (is printing proper value for debug):
  - script: |
      echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=SECRET_PASSWORD]$password"
      echo $(SECRET_PASSWORD)
  - script: |
      echo $(SECRET_PASSWORD)
      pwd 
      cd src/somepath
      npm install --verbose
      npm list --verbose
      npx playwright install 
      npx playwright test tests/someTest.spec.js
    env:
      SECRET_PASSWORD: $(SECRET_PASSWORD)

Then I am going to access this variable in Playwright like this:
  const secretPassword = process.env.SECRET_PASSWORD
  console.log('Secret Password PLAYWRIGHT:', secretPassword); 

And this is resulting in undefined
Do I have to use dotenv for retrieving variables like above?

Your environment variable seems to be set correctly in the pipeline task.
Careful when using task.setvariable with sensitive values. Consider using issecret=true to set a variable as secret.

You can set an environment variable in the bash task with export SECRET_PASSWORD=your_secret_password command.
For example, I tested with the following YAML pipeline.
pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

steps:
- bash: |
    echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=SECRET_PASSWORD]mypassword"
- bash: |
    echo $(SECRET_PASSWORD)
    export SECRET_PASSWORD=$(SECRET_PASSWORD)
    npm install --verbose
    npm list --verbose 
    npx playwright install 
    npx playwright test 

The example.spec.js:
// example.spec.js
const { test, expect } = require('@playwright/test');

test('access environment variable', async ({ page }) => {
    const secretPassword = process.env.SECRET_PASSWORD;
    console.log('Secret Password PLAYWRIGHT:', secretPassword);

});

Test result:

